# Generating correlated random potential using fast Fourier transform

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I would like to generate a random potential in 1D or 2D spaces with a specified autocorrelation function, and according to some mathematical derivations including the Wiener-Khinchin theorem and properties of the Fourier transforms, it turns out that this can be done using the following equation:
[image: Generating potential]
where `phi(k)` is uniformly distributed in interval [0, 1). And this function satisfies [image: phi condition], which is to ensure that the potential generated is always real. 
The autocorrelation function should not affect what I am doing here, and I take a simple Gaussian distribution [image: Autocorrelation].

The choice of the phase term and the condition of `phi(k)` is based on the following properties

1. The phase term must have a modulus of 1 (by Wiener-Khinchin theorem, i.e. the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation of a function equals the modulus of the Fourier transform of that function);
2. The Fourier transform of a real function must satisfy [image: Fourier] (by directly inspecting the definition of Fourier transform in integral form).
3. Both the generated potential and the autocorrelation are real.

By combining these three properties, this term can only take the form as stated above.

For the relevant mathematics, you may refer to p.16 of the following pdf:
https://d-nb.info/1007346671/34

I randomly generated a numpy array using uniform distribution and concatenated the negative of the array with the original array, such that it satisfies the condition of `phi(k)` stated above. And then I performed the numpy (inverse) fast Fourier transform.

I have tried both 1D and 2D cases, and only the 1D case is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## The Gaussian autocorrelation function 
def c(x, V0, rho):
    return V0**2 * np.exp(-x**2/rho**2) 

x_min, x_max, interval_x = -10, 10, 10000
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, interval_x, endpoint=False)

V0 = 1
## the correlation length
rho = 1 

## (Uniformly) randomly generated array for k>0
phi1 = np.random.rand(int(interval_x)/2)
phi = np.concatenate((-1*phi1[::-1], phi1))
phase = np.exp(2j*np.pi*phi)

C = c(x, V0, rho) 
V = ifft(np.power(fft(C), 0.5)*phase)
plt.plot(x, V.real)
plt.plot(x, V.imag)
plt.show()
```

And the plot is similar to what is shown as follows:
[image: Autocorrelation].

However, the generated potential turns out to be complex, and the imaginary parts are of the same order of magnitude as that of the real parts, which is not expected. I have checked the math many times, but I couldn't spot any problems. So I am thinking whether it's related to the implementation problems, for example whether the data points are dense enough for Fast Fourier Transform, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few misunderstandings about how `fft` (more correctly, DFT) operates. 
First note that DFT assumes that the samples of the sequence are indexed as `0, 1, ..., N-1`, where `N` are the number of samples. Instead, you generate a sequence corresponding to indices `-10000, ..., 10000`. Second, note that the DFT of a real sequence will generate real values for the "frequencies" corresponding to `0` and `N/2`. You also seem to not take this into account.

I won't go into further details as this is out of the scope of this stackexchange site.

Just for a sanity check, the code below generates a sequence that has the properties expected for the DFT (FFT) of a real-valued sequence:

- conjugate symmetry of positive and negative frequencies,
- real-valued elements corresponding to frequencies `0` and `N/2`
- sequence assumed to correspond to indices `0` to `N-1`

As you can see, the `ifft` of this sequence indeed generates a real-valued sequence

```
from scipy.fftpack import ifft

N = 32 # number of samples
n_range = np.arange(N) # indices over which the sequence is defined
n_range_positive = np.arange(int(N/2)+1) # the "positive frequencies" sample indices
n_range_negative = np.arange(int(N/2)+1, N) # the "negative frequencies" sample indices

# generate a complex-valued sequence with the properties expected for the DFT of a real-valued sequence
abs_FFT_positive = np.exp(-n_range_positive**2/100)
phase_FFT_positive =  np.r_[0, np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, int(N/2)-1), 0] # note last frequency has zero phase
FFT_positive = abs_FFT_positive * np.exp(1j * phase_FFT_positive)
FFT_negative = np.conj(np.flip(FFT_positive[1:-1]))
FFT = np.r_[FFT_positive, FFT_negative] # this is the final FFT sequence

# compute the IFFT of the above sequence
IFFT = ifft(FFT)

#plot the results

plt.plot(np.abs(FFT), '-o', label = 'FFT sequence (abs. value)')
plt.plot(np.real(IFFT), '-s', label = 'IFFT (real part)')
plt.plot(np.imag(IFFT), '-x', label = 'IFFT (imag. part)')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How should this be adjusted to the two-dimensional case? I've tried to analogously concatenate the uniformly generated matrices in as follows: uniformly generate matrices `matrix1` and `matrix2`, and then concatenate along `axis=0` `np.zeros`, `matrix1`, `np.zeros`, `matrix2`, in the right dimensions, and then define `matrix3 = np.flipur(flipld(matrix2))` and `matrix4 = np.flipur(flipld(matrix1))`, and concatenate along `axis=1` the two above concatenated matrices with an uppermost `np.zeros` and then a `np.zeros` in the middle. But that doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: I guess, however, it's not necessary to correspond each sample to an integer index? The way I indexed also worked as shown in the other answer by Paul Panzer.

Comment: @Sato It *is* necessary to map each sample to an integer index with `0` and `N-1`. This is what `fft`/`ifft` expects. I see a non-zero imaginary component in the other answer, hence I don't see why you claim 'it worked'. I strongly recommend you familiarize yourself with the 1D case first before proceeding to the 2D. Once you done that it would be a straightforward (albeit tedious) exercise to do the 2D case.

Comment: As I adjusted the way to concatenate the arrays and take `x_min, x_max, interval_x = -10, 10, 10000`, the real part has the order of magnitude of 1e-1, while the imaginary part 1e-19, so I guess one may say it has worked by adding more samples into a narrow range?

Comment: Thank you. I will try to look at the 1D case more carefully first.

Comment: Although the disappearance of the imaginary part doesn't imply it's a right answer, I guess a numerical integral should be carried out to check whether the autocorrelation of the obtained potential really recovers the function that we input at the beginning.

Comment: @Sato You are probably right, it does work with the labeling convention you follow. However, note that `fft`/`ifft` will always treat the indices as I described above (even though you have a different convention). Make sure you understand that, since, even though it is not important for this application, it is in others.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, the array in which zeros are inputted is (as in your code) `phase_FFT_positive` but not the array which is inputted to carry out `ifft`. In your code, `FFT` is like `[1, ..., 1... ]`, instead of `[0, ..., 0, ...]`, but it doesn't seem right? Because as far as I understood, it is the array, which is to be directly inputted to carry out `fft` or `ifft`, should have zero padding. But instead in your code it's the phase that has zero padding. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

More care needs to be taken when concatenating:

```
phi1 = np.random.rand(int(interval_x)//2-1)
phi = np.concatenate(([0], phi1, [0], -phi1[::-1]))
```

The first element is the offset (zero frequency mode). "Negative" frequencies come after the midpoint.

This gives me

[image]

Comment: The difference is that I do the mirroring at 0: phi1, phi2, phi3 -> -phi3,-phi2,-phi1,**0**,phi1,phi2,phi3 etc. (It wraps around left of zero), You do it between two grid points: phi1, phi2, phi3 -> -phi3,-phi2,-phi1,phi1,phi2,phi3 which is not how frequencies are arranged in fft.

Comment: I see. And what about the first [0] on the left? I know that without the leftmost [0], the dimension would not have been right, but why exactly must it be zero?

Comment: The zero I was talking about is the left zero. By convention everything left of that zero comes at the end. The other zero only occurs if the order of fft is even. It has to be zero because its the self same mode for phi and -phi (it is at n/2, so you'd get something like exp(2pi k(n/2)/n) which happens to be the same as exp(2pi k(-n/2)/n)

Comment: Thanks. And how this should be adjusted to two-dimensional case? I've tried to analogously concatenate the uniformly generated matrices in the following way: uniformly generate matrices `matrix1` and `matrix2`, and then concatenate along `axis=0` `np.zeros`, `matrix1`, `np.zeros`, `matrix2`, in the right dimensions, and then define `matrix3 = np.flipur(flipld(matrix2))` and `matrix4 = np.flipur(flipld(matrix1))`, and concatenate along `axis=1` the two above concatenated matrices with an uppermost `np.zeros` and then a `np.zeros` in the middle. But that doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: I flipped each of these matrices twice, because, by the math, phi(-k) = -phi(k), and when k is multi-dimensional, then "the element on the other side" should correspond to the mirror image with respect to the "origin", k = (0,0).